# Pure Javascript - Add the value of text input to <li> when button clicked/enter-key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, append

I'm a very new user of Javascript and I'm having trouble with getting the value of a user's input when you click the button or hit enter.  Here is what I have so far, it does indeed add things to the li but it doesn't accept the value.

I'd like this to all be in pure JS (not jQuery).

**Here is my HTML**

```
  <h2>I'd like to bind here</h2>


  <input type="text" class="theplayer" name="Player" id="bind" value="Player-name" />
  <input type="button" id="thego" value="Go" /><br />
```

**And my JS**

```
const el = document.getElementById('bind');
const gobutton = document.getElementById('thego')
let nameOfPlayer = el.value;
gobutton[window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent']( window.addEventListener ? 'click' : 'onclick', myClickFunc, false);
function myClickFunc()
  {
    var x = document.createElement("LI");
    var t = document.createTextNode(nameOfPlayer);
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("teammateys").appendChild(x);
  }
```

Here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/sthig/hhuw0rtr/

Thanks for you help and listening to me get my head around the js verbiage correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an issue with "binding"--there's no such concept in vanilla JS.

Instead you need to make sure that you're grabbing the value of the text field when the onclick handler is called:

```
function myClickFunc()
  {
    var currentValue = document.getElementById("bind").value;
    var x = document.createElement("LI");
    var t = document.createTextNode(currentValue);
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("teammateys").appendChild(x);
  }
```

You can also reduce this to:

```
function myClickFunc()
  {
    var x = document.createElement("li");
    x.textContent = document.getElementById("bind").value;
    document.getElementById("teammateys").appendChild(x);
  }
```

Comment: thanks Faraz, my verbiage is still bad on JS.  Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Perhaps a simple `x.textContent = ...` would be sufficient